# No me obtiene el archivo con jQuery y Ajax en ASP.NET WebForms C#

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net, .net, webforms

Tengo el siguiente código en **Vista.aspx**:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formfile">
        <input type="file" id="myFile"/>
        <div id="btnsave"> Subir fichero.</div>
    </form>
```

En la misma página tengo estos scripts:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
          $('#btnsave').on('click', function (event) {
            Enviar();
            event.preventDefault();
          });
        }) 

function Enviar() {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<%= ResolveUrl("../AjaxHandler.ashx") %>',
        data: new FormData($('#formfile')[0]),
        async: true,
        processData: false, 
        contentType: false,
        success: function (response) {
            alert("success: " + response.d);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert("failure: " + response.d);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("error: " + response.d);
        }
      });
    }
```

En AjaxHandler.ashx:

```
public class AjaxHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)//Aquí siempre da 0
        {
            // Save uploaded file
            HttpPostedFile uploadedFile = context.Request.Files[0];
            uploadedFile.SaveAs(context.Server.MapPath("~/Content/uploads/") + uploadedFile.FileName);
            context.Response.Write("Saved Successfully");
        }
        else {
            
            context.Response.Write("No file attached");
        }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

En AjaxHandler.ashx, **Files = context.Request.Files;** siempre esta vacío. Nunca recibe el archivo.
Coloco un punto de interrupción, y siempre esta vacío. Aunque sí me salta el punto, que quiere decir que está bien enlazado **Vista.aspx con el .ashx** cuando hace la llamada de subir archivos.

Answer (score 0):

Estas intentado enviar un archivo dentro de un json, eso no es posible (al menos de la manera que tú lo estás haciendo.

Puedes ocupar [formdata](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FormData), para hacerlo. Además recuerda colocar enctype="multipart/form-data" en el form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="myFile"/>
<div id="btnsave"> Subir fichero.</div>
</form>
```

```
function Enviar() {
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<%= ResolveUrl("../AjaxHandler.ashx") %>',
        data: new FormData($('form')[0]), 
        async: true,
        processData: false, 
        contentType: false,
        success: function(response) {
        alert("success: " + response.d);
    },
        failure: function(response) {
        alert("failure: " + response.d);
    },
        error: function(response) {
        alert("error: " + response.d);
    }
});
```

Comment: Gracias por responder. Pero en el AjaxHandler.ashx nunca recibo el fichero. Siempre es 0: `context.Request.Files.Count`. Además he intentado cambiando en el js de la llamada ajax el número del form pero nada: `data: new FormData($('form')[1]),` y `data: new FormData($('form')[0]),` No sé si influye ya que es un form dentro de otro (ASP.NET Webforms).

Comment: @Carlos Claro que influye si son 2 forms. Al que tiene el input file debes agregarle una id, por ejemplo "formfile" y luego pones data: new FormData($('#formfile')),

Comment: He añadido un id al form `data: new FormData($('#formfile')[0])` y sigue obteniendo '0 Files'. Ya no sé que puedo estar haciendo mal la verdad. `context.Request.Files.Count` siempre es 0.

Comment: @Carlos Edita tu pregunta original y actualizar el código, además agrega la parte html donde está el form

Comment: Acabo de actualizar el código. Gracias por responder.

Comment: Alguna sugerencia? No entiendo por qué no funciona, se supone que lo tengo todo de la forma correcta.

Comment: Alguna idea? Gracias